# JMSWMQ2013 when connecting from WAS to MQ

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, jaas

I am trying to create a JMS connection from WebSphere App Server 7, but keep getting JMSWMQ2013 (with MQ reason code 2035).  Clearly this is an authentication problem, and I can [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414606/connecting-jms-to-mq-using-mqclient-java-and-mqexplorer-error-jmswmq2013) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889953/unable-to-connect-to-queue-manager-in-websphere-mq-7-1/12914860) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767021/wmq-special-consideration-for-was-clients) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886627/websphere-mq-7-1-help-need-access-or-security/8886813) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012579/websphere-7-configuring-jms-q-connection-factory-without-user-id-mqrc-not-auth) so I have a rough idea of the general problem.

I'm awaiting feedback from our operations team as to the exact configuration of the channel, however, in the meantime I have one observation that is quite puzzling.  If I use WebSphere's JAAS authentication to provide the userid, then I always get the `JMSWMQ2013` error.  , however, if explicitly pass the **same** userid to the JMS queue connection factory's call to `createQueueConnection()`, then I don't get the authentication error.

To be honest, I would have expected both techniques to behave consistently.  Is there some subtlety that I am missing with using JAAS to provide the credentials for a JMS queue connection factory?

**Edit:**  I turned on JMS tracing in WAS using `*=info: JMSApi=all: JMSServer=all: Messaging=all: JMS_WASTraceAdapter=all: com.ibm.mq.*=all: jmsApi=all`, and compared the output line by line.

When using JAAS I can can see that deep in the bowels of `JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl` it is actually calling `WMQConnection.getProcessUserId()` which returns the userid that my WAS instance is running under (which is definitely **not** the user that is defined in the channel's `MCAUSER`).

It is all quite odd... it doesn't seem to be picking up the JAAS authentication entry at all.  My QCF definitely is using CLIENT transport with a mapping configuration alias of DefaultPrincipalMapping, but for some reason it is still using the process's userid instead of the JAAS userid.

Thanks.
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2035 is certainly authentication problem. The user id trying to connect doesn't have access to the MQ resource.

Regarding, your below comment:

> If I use WebSphere's JAAS authentication to provide the userid, then I
>   always get the JMSWMQ2013 error. , however, if explicitly pass the
>   same userid to the JMS queue connection factory's call to
>   createQueueConnection(), then I don't get the authentication error.

Your expectation is correct. Both techniques should behave in the same way. If user id has access then both should connect, if not then both should throw error.

Only explanation to your problem may be, that you are unknowingly sending different user ids in these apps.

Like, your user id is "User123", and it has access to the MQ resource.

However, may be WebSphere's JAAS authentication is sending Domain along with user id.
Say, your user id is in "Developer" domain, then the user id being sent is "Developer\User123", which may not be having access to the resource.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding.  Based on your thoughts about checking the userid, I've updated my original question to provide a bit more info.  It looks like the JAAS credentials are just being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Run IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer as administrator of OS.
Disable identification record of a channel at queue manager properties (menu link/connection or smth like that).